# How to modify the Netbeans Application Configuration?

Tags: maven, configuration, netbeans-platform

I have a Maven Netbeans Application I want to modify its configuration. What do I need to do to change startup parameters from the conf file like: default_options?

I have to manually do it but would like to make it part of the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a netbeans.conf file in your nbm-application project and point the nbm-maven-plugin to it's location - please see http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven/nbm-maven-plugin/cluster-app-mojo.html#etcConfFile

Comment: New URL: http://www.mojohaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/cluster-app-mojo.html#etcConfFile

Answer (score 0):

Create your own ProjectName.conf, for example from default ProjectName.conf file.
Next place it in nbproject folder.
And add to project.conf line like this:

```
app.conf=nbproject/ProjectName.conf
```

[Support for Custom Configuration Files in NetBeans](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/support_for_custom_configuration_files)

Comment: I don't know, but maybe it work too for Maven as for Ant project.